# Set Array size and parse out String user input into Array

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner

I need to set the array's size to be equal to numberResponses so that whatever number the user inputs, the array will be that size no matter how many movies they list. I know I could just declare the array with String[] favMoviesArray = new String(numberResponses); but then I'm not sure how to split the user's response into the different indexes of the array.

````
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Your favorite movies:");
        System.out.println("How many favorite movies do you have?");

        String numberResponsesStr = userInput.nextLine();
        int numberResponses;
            try{
                numberResponses = Integer.parseInt(numberResponsesStr);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number.");
                return;
            }

        if(numberResponses < 1){
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a positive number.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.printf("List your %d favorite movies. Separate them with commas (Movie1, Movie2, Movie3, etc.).", numberResponses);      
        String favMovies = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println();        
        String[] favMoviesArray = favMovies.split("\\s*,\\s*");     
        Arrays.sort(favMoviesArray);

        System.out.printf("Your %d favorite movies are: %n", numberResponses);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(favMoviesArray));

        userInput.close();      
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were thinking would work. You can declare the initial array to be the length specified by the user. Then you need to transfer into it from the split array, no more elements than it can hold, and no more than came out of the split. `Math.min` does that nicely, and I made a loop to do the copying. 
If the user specifies more, only the ones that fit are used; I chose the first ones entered, but if you prefer do the first alphabetically, that's easier and makes for easier sorting. If less, the array is padded with ZZZ entries (which sort to the end).
Here is the result:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Your favorite movies:");
    System.out.println("How many favorite movies do you have?");

    String numberResponsesStr = userInput.nextLine();
    int numberResponses;
    try {
        numberResponses = Integer.parseInt(numberResponsesStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number.");
        return;
    }

    if (numberResponses < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a positive number.");
        return;
    }

    String[] theUltimateArray = new String[numberResponses]; //just like you thought
    for (int i = 0; i < numberResponses; i++) {
        theUltimateArray[i] = "ZZZ"; //start ZZZ, not null, to avoid ugliness and bad sorts, and so these are at the end with this sentinel value
    }

    System.out.printf("List your %d favorite movies. Separate them with commas (Movie1, Movie2, Movie3, etc.).", numberResponses);
    String favMovies = userInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    String[] favMoviesArray = favMovies.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    //Arrays.sort(favMoviesArray); don't sort yet, want the first ones entered, not first alphabetically

    System.out.printf("Your %d favorite movies are: %n", numberResponses);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(favMoviesArray));

    int n = Math.min(numberResponses, favMoviesArray.length); //number we can copy
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //copy
        theUltimateArray[i] = favMoviesArray[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(theUltimateArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theUltimateArray)); //never larger than they said. Filled at end

    userInput.close();
}

}
```